# someone who takes off easily

Tags: idiom-requests, personality

Is there an idiomatic expression to refer to a person who finds it easy to leave wherever they are and go someplace else? - e.g. when friends call out of the blue and invite A. out, he gets dressed and is ready to go; or when A. is tired of living in one place, he packs up and moves to another neighbourhood/ country? In Russian, we say someone like that is 'easy/light to lift'. A friend suggested 'outgoing' and 'gets itchy feet', but it isn't the same.
My student wanted to use this word in an essay about migration, writing "If you've landed a good job and are [this kind of person], why not try moving to another country?"

Comment: It's not specific to leavings (so not given as an 'answer'), but 'at the drop of a hat' is probably what I'd choose: "He's always been ready to leave at the drop of a hat."

Answer (score 1):

- It communicates a lifestyle of moving frequently, rather than a *readiness* to move, but someone who doesn't stay long in one place is a **rolling stone** (from the proverb "A rolling stone gathers no moss," which has a [rather convoluted history](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/rolling-stone-phrase-origin)).
- Not an idiom, but the German loanword [wanderlust](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wanderlust) has been adopted into English: an insatiable urge to travel.
- There are some idioms that communicate the opposite, which you could use in negative. The kind of person you describe is not [tied down](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tied+down), or is not a [homebody](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/homebody) or a [stick-in-the-mud](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stick-in-the-mud).

Comment: *Foot-loose.* . .

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something combining two expressions:

> He's always ready to pack up and go/leave/move at a moment's notice.

or

> He's always ready to pack up and go/leave/move on the spur of the
> moment.

Your "itchy feet" is similar to

**wanderlust**

> A strong desire to travel [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wanderlust)